# Amazon EC2 instance starts automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been using Amazon Web Service Free Tier for 3 months. I have created Amazon EC2 instances and after using them I have closed them immediately. However, I realized that one instance started automatically after terminating. Several times I terminated the instance, and it started to run automatically again. Because of this situation I was charged.

Can anyone show me how to close ec2 instances permenantly ?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you might have setup an autoscaling group, which will try to ensure you have a certain number of instances running.

To check this, login to the EC2 console and look for the Auto Scaling -> Auto Scaling Groups menu item. If you click into that you should be able to see all the current ASGs and could delete them or change the number of instances to 0.

Comment: I think your are right. I had both an auto scaling group and a laungh group.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @c3st7n IMO, you should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: @piotr-aleksander-chmielowski done, thanks.

Answer (score 27):

It sounds like you have setup an autoscaling group, which will try to ensure you have a certain number of instances running.

To check this, login to the EC2 console and look for the Auto Scaling -> Auto Scaling Groups menu item. If you click into that you should be able to see all the current ASGs and could delete them or change the number of instances to 0.

Comment: Yep that was the case

Answer (score 1):

If it is spot instance, make sure you cancel all your **Request spot instance** in the console menu Otherwise it will keep running the instance.